# Making part of the view transparent/overlay while the rest isn't

Tags: iphone

I'd like to show an overlay view similar to what you see when you perform a 'Search in Contacts app where the SearchBar is visible under the toolbar while the gray overlay covers up all of the content below.

For my view, I'd like to have an UITextField and button shown visible while the rest of screen is gray with the rest of the existing contents as grayed-over and no SearchBar.

Things I tried:

1. I can have one view that encases
   both UITextField and button with the
   view's alpha level set to 0.5. But
   this yields grayed appearance for
   everything, including the
   UITextField and button, which is not
   what I'm trying to achieve.
2. I then tried two child views within
   a parent UIView, with one subview
   containing the controls while the
   other one is blank. Set the parent
   UIView to have 0.5 alpha -> this is
   not right either.
3. Continuing with two child views
   within a parent UIView, set the
   parent view to have alpha of 1.0 and
   then the the blank-view to have an
   alpha level of 0.5, it's still not
   right.

So what's a good way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 3 is the way to do it but make sure you're adding them in the right order i.e. transparent view added as first subView to parent view then the text field. This way the text field is on top.

Also, don't forget to set the `backgroundColor` attribute of the parent view to `[UIColor clearColor]`.

Comment: thanks this worked in conjunction with a Controller and added the main transparent view as the topmost.

Answer (score 0):

I would've thought #3 would be the correct way to do it.  Are you sure you have the parent and the overlay views's `opaque` property set to `NO`?

Comment: Parent UIView alpha set to 1.0, opaque: not checked. Blank-subview alpha set to 0.5, opaque: checked. When you say 'overlay', are you referring to the blank-subview or something else?

Comment: Yes, I meant the "blank" overlay (presumably it's not really blank, but a solid black).  Also, follow Ramin's advice and make sure the parent view's backgroundColor is [UIColor clearColor].